# Winston file transport Age

Tags: node.js, winston

Is is possible to set the age of the logfile when using file-transport for winston. Can we set the age/time for the file "server.log" to 24hours, so it get auto deleted after 24hours and a new file with the same name get created, thereby saving memory?

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'logs/server.log',handleExceptions: true }),
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DailyRotateFile transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#dailyrotatefile-transport) will let you set a time when a new log file is created. You can then delete old ones with a cron job.

Comment: Thanks. This really worked well with node-schedule and find-remove to manage the logs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Winston doesn't support that.

These kind of problems are normally solved by rotating your logs (writing to a new file every day, eg: `log_2015-02-23.txt`, `log_2015-02-24.txt`, etc) and then deleting obsolete ones with a cron job, like in [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136804/cron-job-to-delete-files-older-than-3-days).